# Facebook Native Ads on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to implement native ads from Facebook in my app. I put the code exactly like Facebook said, and it works. But only if the app was installed via xCode. If the app is installed via Test Flight the ads never appears.
Any ideas?

My Audience Network permission is enable, as well as my ad placement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have facing this problem when using Testflight beta testing, I switch to Fabric beta testing and the facebook native ad shows.
Just put the app on app store and will be fine.

Remember to uncheck the "Limit Ad Tracking" in the device settings.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#a12

Comment: Thanks @Teng, actually I just release the app and the ads works :)

Answer (score 4):

I know, this question is already answered. I am adding information to help someone looking for explanation.

Test Flight rotates through a pool of IDFA's and hides the users true IDFA, making it difficult to identify a Facebook user – and that is required for delivering an ad.

Comment: If you use Fabric to distribute your beta app, its works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this so I used one of my tickets to open a chat with someone at apple via members center. They advised me to give the app 24-48 hours of being live for iAds to work correctly on all devices. They said that Xcode should always display iAds but other methods of deploying iAds may be a bit behind.