# Facebook Audience Network lock HTTP request

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, facebook-audience-network, xamarin-component

I have a big issue with FB Audience component.

We have integrating Facebook Audience Network on iOS with a placement_id but on different devices and FB accounts API answer is always this

> [FBAudienceNetworkLog/FBAdProvider:137 ] Ad request error: Error Domain=com.facebook.ads.sdk Code=1001 "No fill" UserInfo={FBAdErrorDetailKey={ msg = "No fill. We are not able to serve ads to this person. Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#a12. If you are integrating Audience Network for the first time, you can use test ads https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing."; }, NSLocalizedDescription=No fill}

We have referred also docs a12 but there are "No limits on iOS ads" and all accounts are logged to Facebook.
We have read carefully documentation and we have check condition of "No fill" on iOS and Android.

We would like to use Facebook Native Ads in our listing and each 5 elements we want show 1 Facebook Native Ads.

What is strange is this case (on same device):

- Installing app in DEBUG MODE Facebook Native Ads are shown correctly
- Installing app in RELEASE MODE USING TESTFLIGHT Facebook Native Ads respond "No Fill"
- Releasing same TestFlight app on APPSTORE, Facebook Native Ads LOCK others HTTP requests. We have check it via Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and API call does not start because is in loading Facebook call. This happens on all devices that download app via APPSTORE.

Our app is developed via Xamarin Component https://components.xamarin.com/view/fbaudiencenetworkios

What seems really strange is same code on same device and same FB user (mine Luigi Saggese) on different release type have different behaviour.

- Debug Mode: OK
- Release Mode using TestFlight: "No Fill" without locking other API calls
- App Store: No response locking other API calls

On TestFlight mode we have found this answer on StackOverflow that seems realistic ([Facebook Native Ads on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779758/facebook-native-ads-on-ios)) "Test Flight rotates through a pool of IDFA's and hides the users true IDFA, making it difficult to identify a Facebook user – and that is required for delivering an ad."

Answer (score 0):

Here are some feedback on your three scenarios:

Scenario 1: This seems work without issue. Good for you.

Scenario 2: Receiving "NO Fill" when running app from TestFlight. This is a known issue. Many posts in this site already identified root cause. You also list the reason at the end of your post too. The suggestion is to get off TestFlight if you want to test the real ads rather than Facebook test ads.

Scenario 3: This is an interesting one. Normally most of time, debug and release version should behave similarly. Audience Network component is a very simple one. We observed several cases like this and noticed the main issue is multiple background threads are running and caused unexpected lock of network.

Besides ask help from peers here, another good channel is to submit a direct support case on Facebook Audience Network's developer dashboard. The FAN technical team will be able to check the issue with you.

Comment: about suggestion to contact FAN technical team, i have already done but they have remind me to Xamarin support team (because component it's not maintained by FAN). I have reported a bug here https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40325